# Delete `··`, Replace `············` with `······` eslint() eslintprettier/prettier

Tags: typescript, eslint, react-typescript, typescript-eslint

I am using eslint, prettier and typescript. after configuring `indent:"error"` in `.eslintrc`, it is showing the below three types of errors.

`Delete` ⏎`eslintprettier/prettier`

`Delete` ··``

`Replace` ············`with`······``

all the above are from rule `eslintprettier/prettier`

What is the possible reason for the issue and
what correct config should we follow to fix/avoid/overcome these types of issue.

[image: This is how it looks like]

Comment: It means you should indent with 2 spaces rather than 4. It just shows a space/blank as `·` to make it easier to count.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's telling you to indent with less spaces. The dots are just for counting it. This is coming from the Prettier plugin.

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer to intend with four spaces, and want Prettier to help enforce that, you can accomplish this by making a `.prettierrc` file and paste this code into it:

```
{
"tabWidth":4    
}
```